# Merge parent and child pom during assembly

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a multi-module maven project. I want to assembly each of the child so when they are uncompressed and executed with maven to not depend on the parent pom.

Is there a way with assembly plugin to kind of "merge" the parent pom and the child pom?

Original project:

```
├── pom.xml
├── README.md
├── module1
│   ├── assembly.xml
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── README.md
│   └── src
└── module2
    ├── assembly.xml
    ├── pom.xml
    ├── README.md
    └── src
```

Assembly package (zip):

```
moduleX
├── pom.xml  <-- merged pom
├── README.md
└── src
```

The packaged assembly will be used by an external client outside from our organization, so he doesn't have access to our repositories.

**Update:** 
As JF Meier suggested, using `flatten-maven-plugin` solves my issue.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>flatten</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>flatten</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <flattenMode>bom</flattenMode>
                            <pomElements>
                                <build>keep</build>
                            </pomElements>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

And then on my assembly.xml I just add the generated `.flattened-pom.xml` and rename it to pom.xml:

```
<files>
    <file>
        <source>.flattened-pom.xml</source>
        <destName>pom.xml</destName>
    </file>
</files>
```

Comment: Make your `moduleX` part of the multi module build (add `moduleX` in the directory try and add `<module>moduleX</module>` in your parent `pom.xml`); define all modules you would like to package inside your `moduleX` as a dependency of `moduleX` and than you create a zip/tar.gz etc. via maven-assembly-plugin...

Comment: I don't understand the `..assembly each of the child...` ? The modules are already created as `jar` or `war` depending on the packaging you have given?

Comment: All the modules must be packaged as compressed files, on their own, separate from each other. The structure of each compressed package is as I described above. Once they are uncompressed, the client only needs to do `mvn test`.

Comment: What kind of compressed files? Hm..I don't understand the step `..the client only needs to do mvn test` ? Do you create a library or test library? Then someone can simply use the `jar`'s directly no need to make a supplemental compression/compressed files? Really confusing what kind of problem you really have?

Comment: They are not jars. The modules are composed of scripts that use maven executions. Once we assembly the modules, we share them to the client.

Comment: Sounds more confusing ...why do you need scripts for maven executions? Apart from that if you have module which is part of a multi module build you need to have the whole structure to be able to built one or more modules of it ...So in the end I don't understand the idea behind your concept (for me it sounds wrong) so I can't give you a good suggestions how to go...So if a client uses `mvn test`..does that mean to build the module separately? If yes your approach is wrong ...?..??

Comment: Let me elaborate then... They are testing suites (each module), which originally requires the client to do many steps in order to execute them. I've realized that many of these steps can be automated with maven executions, so I decided to "mavenize" it. This also will help us to integrate it easily with Jenkins for our development life cycle. I use a parent pom because they share common resources and maven executions. We can decide to deliver a single assembly altogether with the parent pom and problem solved but currently each test suite is delivered separately, so that's why I'm asking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like the

https://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/

It allows you to "merge" the parent POM into your POM.

Comment: do you know if it's possible to not expand variables?

Comment: I've found it https://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/apidocs/index.html By using `keep` option.